# Know when the items finished loading the BaseAdapter in a gridview

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I have a gridview that filled with a dynamic adapter using AsyncTask, the detail is q appear delayed gridview, I wonder if you can tell when finishes filling the gridview to show a progressbar while filling, thanks

Comment: please show some code...

Answer (score 0):

If you use AsyncTask you got the progress report method (safe to ui thread) and the completed method(also ui thread safe) , you just need to override them, for you simple case show a progress before task starts and hide it on complete.